# Angular 2 Portal with multiple apps

Tags: angular, shell, typescript, portal

I am building a portal using Angular 2. The portal should be able to host multiple applications(portlets) and should serve as a container. The portlets also would be built with/without angular 2. They would be independent project managed by independent teams. The portal manages the authentication, push notifications, messages to/from the portlets. The idea is that if a portlet eg. App1, is built and released and becomes visible inside the portal and if any change/bug fix is needed for the App1, it has to happen without a release of the Portal. Can you please sugggest some options for me here ? Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to build a CMS system. Is that correct?

Comment: It is not exactly a CMS, but a portal that can host multiple apps and apps should be able to be managed independently.

Comment: Did you come up with any solutions to this? Have a similar problem myself.  Iframes seem to be the go to solution

Comment: Same here. Please let us know about the solutions you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by building a reusable component, a Header with Menubar. The Menubar is intelligent enough to navigate to parts(routes) of your existing application, and navigate to other portals, external links etc. If any application wants to get onboarded, they simply inject a script and the menu bar comes on top of their application.

And of course, the menu in the menubar is bound to the users entitlements which will be a centralised entitlement system.